# jquery - can I detect once all content is loaded?

Tags: jquery, events, python-idle

I have a page with a lot of ads being loaded in piece by piece.

I need to position an element relative to overall page height, which is changing during load, because of ads being added.

**Question**: Is there a jquery event or similar to detect, when all elements are loaded? I'm currently "waiting" with setTimeout, but this is far from nice.

An *idle* event would be nice, which fires once after pageload if no new http requests are made for xyz secs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `onload` event which triggers when ALL elements eg DOM, images, frames and external resources have loaded into the page.

Vanilla JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function(){ ......... }
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function() {.........});
```

- `window.onload`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload
- `$(window).load` : http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: The function is executed when the $(window) is done loading the DOM. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: My bad, @frequent: sorry for the bad info.

Comment: ok, question answered, but still tricky. I'm using a Jquery Mobile multipage, which has several pages inside the DOM which you can transition to and from. The _onload_ fires correctly on the inital page of the multipage - cause everything is loaded - including all the other pages. So when I transition to the 2nd, 3rd... page I don't have an event to fire. Guess this is for another question.

Answer (score 0):

There's no idle function, but there is

```
$(window).load(function () {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the answer would be `$(function(){ })` or `window.onload = function(){}` that fires after all the DOM contents are loaded. But I guess, the ads on your page starts loading asynchronously after the DOM load.

So, assuming you know the number of 'ads' on your page (you said you are loading them piece by piece), my advise would be to increment a counter on each successful 'ad' load. When that counter reaches the total number of ads, you fire a 'all_adv_loaded' function.

Comment: also a nice approach, but since this is for a plugin I would have to get by without knowing the exact number of ads.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  //loading bar here /gif imagel
  loader(); 
  //will call at the end of window load
});

function Loader(){
  //Your main function here complete webpage
};
```